# Direct Coding XAML in C# (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Is there a way to directly write XAML code for a bound variable in C#? What I mean by this is, if I have an XAML object databound to a C# variable, would I be able to directly write XAML code for that variable and have it displayed in XAML? For example, if I have a table field bound to some C# variable i, would there be a way I could set i to "Hi" and have that interpretted by XAML and the proper button displayed?

I hope I explained this clearly enough.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You can create bindings in C# as well as XAML which get compiled to the same code.

Comment: I suggest you post a more specific example, preferably with a class and a first stab at the XAML, even if it's not functional.

Comment: Basically Im working with a class I didn't write that displays data in a table format . The way it takes the data as input is by referencing databound variables. The problem is that I want to add buttons to this table and there's no way to add that from the XAML end. Thus if the bound variable values could be XAML code then I could just set them to buttons and have buttons displayed on my table.

Comment: @user2476060 - XAML doesn't work that way. You should be able to create the buttons in C# and bind them to the table.

Comment: @ChrisF - how do you initialize a button in C#?

Comment: @user2476060 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx `var myButton = new Button();`

Comment: Please post the relevant code and XAML. I'm really having a hard time to understand your request. Also, what exactly do you mean by "add buttons to table"?

Comment: @ChrisF creating UI elements in procedural code is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @HighCore "almost always" - agreed. Though in this case the OP states he can't change the XAML. Therefore to get new UI elements into the page he's going to have to create them in code.